# Change label in window

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to change label in vc++ window. the label shows real time data which updates every100 milliseconds. So how can i do this in vc++ window? Any one please help

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hRPMEx,hAvgTimeEx;
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch(message)
    {
    case WM_TIMER:
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
        hRPMEx  = CreateWindowA("Static","",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
            20,100,220,25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_RPM_EX, hInstance, NULL);  

        hAvgTimeEx  = CreateWindowA("Static","",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT, 
            20,150,220,25,
            hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_AVGTIME_EX, hInstance, NULL);  
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:

        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDC_BTN_CONNECT:
            break;

        case IDC_RPM_EX:
            break;

        case IDC_BTN_DISCONNECT:
            break;

        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;

        case IDM_OPEN:
            break;

        case IDM_EXIT:
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }

        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

return 0;
}
```

where should i give call to function which updates label(Static Text)

Comment: This looks very contrived: you have managed to write the code above, but do not understand anything about it? How about we say that this is **HOMEWORK**, and you need a hint or two. Then here's a hint: check out the *documentation* of each thing in the code.

Comment: You also need to learn about _indentation_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things :

1. To update something regularly, you can use a timer. An example :

   ```
       // To set the timer
       SetTimer(hwnd,             // handle to main window 
       IDT_TIMER1,            // timer identifier 
       10000,                 // 10-second interval 
       (TIMERPROC) NULL);     // no timer callback 

       // In you WindProc Callback :
       case WM_TIMER:
       {
           if ( wParam == IDT_TIMER1)
           {
                 // put your code here
           } 

       }
   ```

Example from here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx

1. To change a window's label :

   ```
   BOOL WINAPI SetWindowText(
     _In_      HWND hWnd,
     _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpString
   );
   ```

Example from here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx